# WSO2 ESB Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to install the Eclipse plugin for **WSO2 ESB**.

I am following the instructions from the [Installation Guide](http://wso2.org/project/tools/esb/esb-authoring/1.0.0/docs/install_guide.html#install1) but the address http://tools.wso2.org/eclipse/ was not available for the last 5 days.

Are there any alternative links where I can download the plugin?

Comment: WSO2 now provides a Carbon studio for all SOA products. It is Eclipse-based and has ESB support as well. 

So this is probably what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The link you are referring to, seems to be outdated. [Carbon Studio](http://wso2.com/products/carbon-studio/) provides Eclipse based tooling support for WSO2 products. You can find the installation guide for latest version of Carbon Studio [here](http://wso2.org/project/carbon-studio/1.0.14/docs/install_guide.html).

Comment: Thank you, I am using the Carbon Studio now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's now named as [Carbon Studio](http://wso2.com/products/carbon-studio/) which includes the WSO2 ESB support. Follow the installation guide of the current latest version [1.0.14](http://wso2.org/project/carbon-studio/1.0.14/docs/install_guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Latest version 3.6.0 of WSO2 Developer Studio has released with Eclipse Kepler Migration and the distribution is available to download at [1](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) and the latest product documentation is available at [2](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS360/WSO2+Developer+Studio+Documentation).